# Statistical Mechanics-- how does a changing energy affect the probability of a particle to be in a certain state?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am doing some self-directed Stat Mech learning, and am curious about the relationship between energy and the probability of a particle being in a specific energy state. If energy is required to change a particles state (ie through bonding), which state is more likely? What is the general relationship between energy and state probability? Obviously it is less likely for particles to be in a higher energy state, but what is the relationship?

Comment: Have you gotten to Boltzmann distributions yet?

Comment: @G.Lang no... i'll assume that will explain this to me?